# How to get AWS credentials and access to S3 on Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, amazon-s3, docker-compose

I'm setting up Docker containers.

On the server side, files are uploaded to S3.

It succeeded to upload under my local environment.

However, it fails to upload under Docker environment.

- client: React/axios
- server: Golang/gin
- db: mysql
- source code: https://github.com/jpskgc/article

```
article
　├ client
　├ api  
　└ docker-compose.yml
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    ports:
      - 2345:2345
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.aws/credentials.properties:/home/api/.aws/credentials.properties
```

Here is the server side code to access to S3.

```
api := router.Group("/api")
{
    api.POST("/post/image", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var creds *credentials.Credentials
        var err error

        creds = credentials.NewSharedCredentials("", "default")
        _, err = creds.Get()

        if err != nil {
            creds = credentials.NewCredentials(&ec2rolecreds.EC2RoleProvider{})
            _, err = creds.Get()
        }

        cfg := aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("ap-northeast-1").WithCredentials(creds)
        svc := s3.New(session.New(), cfg)

        form, _ := c.MultipartForm()

        files := form.File["images[]"]

        var imageNames []ImageName
        imageName := ImageName{}

        for _, file := range files {

            f, err := file.Open()

            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }

            defer f.Close()

            size := file.Size
            buffer := make([]byte, size)

            f.Read(buffer)
            fileBytes := bytes.NewReader(buffer)
            fileType := http.DetectContentType(buffer)
            path := "/media/" + file.Filename
            params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
                Bucket:        aws.String("article-s3-jpskgc"),
                Key:           aws.String(path),
                Body:          fileBytes,
                ContentLength: aws.Int64(size),
                ContentType:   aws.String(fileType),
            }
            resp, err := svc.PutObject(params)

            fmt.Printf("response %s", awsutil.StringValue(resp))

            imageName.NAME = file.Filename

            imageNames = append(imageNames, imageName)
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, imageNames)
    })
}
```

I expect images are uploaded in server side to S3.

But in actuality they're not.

Here are some logs:

```
api_1     | 2019/07/31 14:58:53 [Recovery] 2019/07/31 - 14:58:53 panic recovered:
api_1     | POST /api/post/image HTTP/1.1
api_1     | Host: localhost:2345
api_1     | Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
api_1     | Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
api_1     | Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
api_1     | Connection: keep-alive
api_1     | Content-Length: 92267
api_1     | Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYx6aOI06AYceIHnU
api_1     | Origin: http://localhost:3000
api_1     | Referer: http://localhost:3000/post/finish
api_1     | User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
api_1     | 
api_1     | 
api_1     | runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:82 (0x4427f0)
api_1     |     panicmem: panic(memoryError)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:390 (0x44261f)
api_1     |     sigpanic: panicmem()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/ec2metadata/api.go:26 (0xa01a35)
api_1     |     (*EC2Metadata).GetMetadata: req := c.NewRequest(op, nil, output)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/ec2rolecreds/ec2_role_provider.go:134 (0xa05607)
api_1     |     requestCredList: resp, err := client.GetMetadata(iamSecurityCredsPath)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/ec2rolecreds/ec2_role_provider.go:90 (0xa05159)
api_1     |     (*EC2RoleProvider).Retrieve: credsList, err := requestCredList(m.Client)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/credentials.go:241 (0x945246)
api_1     |     (*Credentials).Get: creds, err := c.provider.Retrieve()
api_1     | /app/main.go:172 (0xb1dde1)
api_1     |     main.func5: _, err = creds.Get()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x8f97c9)
api_1     |     (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/recovery.go:83 (0x90d259)
api_1     |     RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x8f97c9)
api_1     |     (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/logger.go:240 (0x90c300)
api_1     |     LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x8f97c9)
api_1     |     (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:391 (0x9036c9)
api_1     |     (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:352 (0x902dbd)
api_1     |     (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774 (0x6dcc77)
api_1     |     serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878 (0x6d8860)
api_1     |     (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337 (0x45a090)
api_1     |     goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
api_1     | 
api_1     | [GIN] 2019/07/31 - 14:58:53 | 500 |    695.0698ms |      172.18.0.1 | POST     /api/post/image
```

Comment: Your `nil` panic stems from [this code](https://github.com/jpskgc/article/blob/3dda7fb4f96d04085fbb0241d185fc73a3016b7a/api/main.go#L171-L172). Your creating a zero-value `ec2rolecreds.EC2RoleProvider{}` which has a field `Client` of type `*ec2metadata.EC2Metadata`. Since you're not setting it, it's `nil`, so somewhere in the call stack for `creds.Get()` something is trying to dereference that `nil` pointer...

Comment: ...  Since you're mounting your local `credentials.properties` into your container, you could use [`credentials.NewSharedCredentials(...)`](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials#NewSharedCredentials) instead of `credentials.NewCredentials(&ec2rolecreds.EC2RoleProvider{})`. Ultimately mounting credentials file from your local workstation into your production server container isn't going to be a great idea, and you should look into the other ways of constructing a `*credentials.Credentials`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set environment variable in `docker-compose.yml` and set value in console.

```
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws --profile default configure get aws_access_key_id)
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws --profile default configure get aws_secret_access_key)
```

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(os.Getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), os.Getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"), "")
```

Comment: You can use the provided "helper" `creds := credentials.NewEnvCredentials()`. Might be a new addition, not sure ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your credentials using environment variables like this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy
```

So your docker-compose will look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: YOUR-SECRET-KEY
    ports:
      - 2345:2345
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
```

You shouldn't do this in production and use IAM profiles instead both for the simplicity of not having a ton of keys everywhere, and for security to avoid leaking you keys in logs or anywhere, but it works well for development purpose.

Is you use this method, you can remove the credentials part of your code, more informations here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made AWS SDK for Go V2 happy by mounting the host .aws directory to the docker container docker-compose.yml:

```
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.aws/credentials:/.aws/credentials:ro
```

The SDK looks for `.aws` directory under `$HOME` directory so you may need to find out what `HOME` env is in the docker container and then update accordingly.